# How to delete the records in local table using sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can **able to insert** the records into the temp table. From the same temp table **i need to delete the records** according to another condition

**Here is my code :**

```
DECLARE @tempDataTable Table
(
    Id bigint,
    Title varchar(max),
    Forename varchar(max),
    Surname varchar(max),
    Addr1 varchar(max),
    Addr2 varchar(max),
    Addr3 varchar(max),
    Village varchar(max),
    Town varchar(max),
    Postcode varchar(max),
    LatestER varchar(50),
    RowNum bigint
)

DECLARE @sqlQuery varchar(max)

SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT [Id]
    ,[Title]
    ,[ForName]
    ,[Surname]
    ,[Addr1]
    ,[Addr2]
    ,[Addr3]
    ,[Village]
    ,[Town]
    ,[Postcode]
    ,[LatestER]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (DomicileId) ORDER BY Title) as RowNum
FROM [dbo].[DPS_DataRegion_Scotland]
WHERE (' + @searchFilteredDataCondition + ')'

INSERT INTO @tempDataTable
EXEC (@sqlQuery)
```

The Above part is working fine. Here i need to delete the records from **@tempDataTable**

```
SET @sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM '+ @tempDataTable +'
WHERE (' + @searchFilteredTownCondition + ')'

EXEC (@sqlQuery)
```

**While inserting it throws an error of - Must declare the scalar variable "@tempDataTable".**

Comment: Why don't you use a "normal" temp table instead of table var? Temp tables are visible from inner scope. Table vars can also negatively affect the cardinality estimates and the exec plan for the query.

Comment: @dean k after query executes i need to delete the temp table ah?

Comment: Depends whether your code is in a stored proc or not; a temp table's lifespan in a stored proc is managed automatically (ie dropped when SP returns); outside the SP, a temp table is dropped automatically when the session goes away. You can always drop it manually, but in a SP better leave it to the engine to manage it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to use the name of the variable in your dynamic SQL, like

```
SET @sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM @tempDataTable'
```

But you won't be able to use your table variable inside dynamic SQL this way - it won't be visible inside the scope of that dynamic SQL execution. You would have to declare everything inside one dynamic SQL batch and use one `EXEC` or use temporary tables.

The latter would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempDataTable
(
    Id bigint,
    Title varchar(max),
    Forename varchar(max),
    Surname varchar(max),
    Addr1 varchar(max),
    Addr2 varchar(max),
    Addr3 varchar(max),
    Village varchar(max),
    Town varchar(max),
    Postcode varchar(max),
    LatestER varchar(50),
    RowNum bigint
)

DECLARE @sqlQuery varchar(max)

SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT [Id]
    ,[Title]
    ,[ForName]
    ,[Surname]
    ,[Addr1]
    ,[Addr2]
    ,[Addr3]
    ,[Village]
    ,[Town]
    ,[Postcode]
    ,[LatestER]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (DomicileId) ORDER BY Title) as RowNum
FROM [dbo].[DPS_DataRegion_Scotland]
WHERE (' + @searchFilteredDataCondition + ')'

INSERT INTO #tempDataTable
EXEC (@sqlQuery)

SET @sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM #tempDataTable WHERE (' + @searchFilteredTownCondition + ')'

EXEC (@sqlQuery)
```

Comment: Yep, because you're building a string to execute so all you want is the string of the table name which in this case is `@tempDataTable`.

Comment: @Vignesh Well, almost the same, now it doesn't recognise the **table** variable. Let me work on it.

Comment: If multiple user(s) access the same page means it wont work kno... For every search new table will be created?

Comment: Local temporary table (with one `#`) are visible to only one connection - the one that created them.

Comment: @Szymon so i need to delete that table after query completes ah?

Comment: They also get deleted if you close your connection so in some cases you don't need to explicitly delete them. But you have to delete them before you create them again *on the same connection*.

Answer (score 0):

> While inserting it throws an error of - Must declare the scalar variable "@tempDataTable".

Did you ever look at the SQL you are sending to the server? Not the source. Basically print out the SQL.

SET @sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM '+ @tempDataTable +'

translated into

```
DELETE FROM (content of @tempDataTable)
```

if you want to use @tempdataTable as name of a table, make it part of the string, not a parameter.

```
SET @sqlQuery = 'DELETE FROM @tempDataTable'
```

Comment: By doing this process also it throws the same error while executing

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid using dynamic SQL unless it is absolutely essential. Your problem is that you are using @tempDataTable as if it is a string variable to build up a dynamic SQL statement.

It is a table variable, therefore you can use it in the same way as an actual table, ie:

```
DELETE FROM @tempDataTable
```

Can you give some examples of the values being stored in @searchFilteredTownCondition? It would be easier if you could replace this with column names and comparison values passed in individual variables - then you could dispense with the dynamic SQL.

Comment: Declare #searchFilteredTownData varchar(max);   SET #searchFilteredTownData = 'AB10'         SET #searchFilteredTownData = '[Town] Not like ''%' + #searchFilteredTownData + '%'''
   SET #searchFilteredTownData = replace(#searchFilteredTownData, #searchFilteredDataFindString, #likeTownReplaceString)
   SET #searchFilteredTownCondition = 
#searchFilteredTownData

Comment: You make this a lot simpler - eg if you are just filtering on town, declare a Town variable: `code`DECLARE @Town varchar(100)`code` then add a where clause to your SQL statement: `code`WHERE (Town NOT LIKE '%' + @Town + '%' OR @Town IS NULL)`code` - then you can just run the SQL directly without having to use EXEC

Comment: You're welcome - let me know if you need any help with the WHERE clause and parameters